# d3 real time graph syncing issues

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, real-time

I've spent several days trying to create a real-time timeline where data is appended asynchronously. It seems impossible to get things working smoothly without breaking something else each time.

I had a look at several examples but none of them seem to match my case. Namely, most of the real-time examples either rely on the data to increment the timeline by a step each time, or either they all assume that the data comes continuously in regular intervals.

Issues I'm having:

1. Points slide nicely. However if I switch a tab and switch back they continue from where they left, and thus not matching the current ticks in the x axis
2. The ticks in the timeline every now and then get some weird transition that looks like shuffling. After the shuffling the actual points are out of sync with the timeline.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rn8d7u6q/2/)

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en">
<head><script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script></head>
<body><script>

    const LENGTH = 10 // in seconds
    const TICKS = 10 // num of ticks in time axis
    const HEIGHT = 240
    const WIDTH = 950
    const MARGIN_LEFT = 40
    const MARGIN_TOP = 40
    var datapoints = []

    // Create root element + background rect
    svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
      .attr('width', WIDTH)
      .attr('height', HEIGHT)
    svg.append('rect')
      .attr('width', '100%')
      .attr('height', '100%')
      .attr('fill', 'rgba(59, 58, 52, 0.8)')
    $graphs = svg.append('g')
    $slidables = $graphs.append('g')

    // We use two scalers for x. This solves the issue with the axis being out
    // of sync
    scaleX = d3.scaleTime().range([MARGIN_LEFT, WIDTH-MARGIN_LEFT])
    scaleY = d3.scaleLinear().range([MARGIN_TOP, HEIGHT-MARGIN_TOP])
    updateTimeScale()

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    function logDate(date){
      console.log(date.toTimeString().split(' GMT')[0] + ' ' + date.getMilliseconds() + 'ms')
    }

    function logPoint(point){
      const date = point[0]
      console.log(
          date.toTimeString().split(' GMT')[0] + ' ' + date.getMilliseconds() + 'ms, ',
          point[1]
      )
    }

    function oneSecondAgo(){
      d = new Date()
      d.setSeconds(d.getSeconds() - 1)
      return d
    }

    function leftDate(){
      d = new Date()
      d.setSeconds(d.getSeconds() - LENGTH)
      return d
    }

    function tickDist(){
        return scaleX(new Date()) - scaleX(oneSecondAgo())
    }


    // -------------------------------- Init -----------------------------------

    /* Resets timescale to the current time */
    function updateTimeScale(){
      right = new Date()
      left = new Date()
      right.setSeconds(right.getSeconds())
      left.setSeconds(right.getSeconds()-LENGTH)
      scaleX.domain([left, right])
    }

    function init(){
      // Setup axis
      xaxis = d3.axisBottom(scaleX).ticks(TICKS)
      $xaxis = svg.append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0, ' + (HEIGHT - MARGIN_TOP) + ')')
        .call(xaxis)
      yaxis = d3.axisLeft(scaleY)
      $yaxis = svg.append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + MARGIN_LEFT + ', 0)')
        .call(yaxis)

      // Garbage collect old points every second
      setInterval(function(){
          while (datapoints.length > 0 && scaleX(datapoints[0][0]) <= MARGIN_LEFT){
            datapoints.shift()
          }
          $slidables.selectAll('circle')
            .data(datapoints, d=>d)
            .exit()
            .remove()
      }, 1000)

      // Slide axis at interval
      function tick(){
        right = new Date()
        left = new Date()
        right.setSeconds(right.getSeconds()+1)
        left.setSeconds(right.getSeconds()-LENGTH)
        scaleX.domain([left, right])
        $xaxis.transition()
          .ease(d3.easeLinear)
          .duration(new Date() - oneSecondAgo())
          .call(xaxis)
      }
      tick()
      setInterval(tick, 1000)
    }

    // ------------------------------ Update -----------------------------------

    /* Update graph with points

    We always set right edge to current time
    */
    function update(points){
      datapoints = datapoints.concat(points)
      logPoint(points[0])
      updateTimeScale()

      // Add new points, transition until left edge and then remove
      $slidablesEnter = $slidables.selectAll('circle')
        .data(datapoints, d=>d)
        .enter()
      $slidablesEnter
        .append("circle")
        .style("fill", "rgb(74, 255, 0)")
        .attr("r", 2)
        .attr("cx", p=>scaleX(p[0]))  // put it at right
        .attr("cy", p=>scaleY(p[1]))
      .transition()
        .duration(function(p){
          remainingTime = p[0] - leftDate()
          return remainingTime
        })
        .ease(d3.easeLinear)
        .attr("cx", p => MARGIN_LEFT)
        .remove()
    }

    // Start everything with two random datapoints
    init()
    d1 = new Date()
    d2 = new Date()
    d2.setMilliseconds(d2.getMilliseconds()-1500)
    update([[d1, Math.random()]])
    update([[d2, Math.random()]])

</script></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just some updates. My workaround is to repaint everything on a tiny interval (i.e. 20ms).

This solves all the syncing issues but not sure if there will be a difference on performance.

Something like this

```
function tick(){
        // Redraw all elements
        scaleX.domain([now(-TIMELINE_LENGTH_MS), now()])
        $slidables.selectAll('circle')
          .data(datapoints, d=>d)
          .attr("cx", p =>  scaleX(p[0]))
          .transition()
          .duration(0)
}
setInterval(tick, REFRESH_INTERVAL)
```

Setting `REFRESH_INTERVAL` to 20ms, looks pretty much the same as having a transition. Anything above starts looking chopppy, but at least is more accurate than before.